# Stream Reader (Pull data from .txt file to be displayed in listBox)

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a .txt file that, in the **form2**, I am writing to. I now need to call up the .txt file and then display each line of characters into a listBox on **form3**. But I am getting errors.

> Error1: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'string'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> Error2: Cannot convert method group 'ReadLine' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

**Side Note** the file is named "**data.txt**" and form 3 is named "**Stats**".

```
public partial class Stats : Form
{
    public Stats()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Stats_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader StreamIn = File.OpenText(@"data.txt");
        string Record = StreamIn.ReadLine();

        while (Record != null)
        {
            listBox1.Text.Add(Record);
            Record = StreamIn.ReadLine;
        }
        StreamIn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `listBox1.Text` is a `String` and it doesn't have `Add` method... Do you mean `listBox1.Text += Record`?

Comment: Error1: use StringBuilder in this case and then set its text to listBox1

Comment: Error2: use ReadLine() and wrap your StreamReader in using statemt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`listBox1.Text` is of type `string`. `String` does not have an `Add` function. The property `Text` represents the selected item, not the collection of items. You can add items to the `Items` property", like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Record);
```

Second, all methods must end with `(` zero or more parameters and `)`:

```
Record = StreamIn.ReadLine();
```

You do it correctly in the line of code where you read a record.

*** EDIT (after comments of Dmitry Bychenko) ***

Another way to do it faster is:

```
private void Stats_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"data.txt"));
}
```

Comment: `listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"data.txt"));` will be even better: `listBox1` will *not be redrawn* after each added item

Comment: The method `AddRange` does not exist in the ItemCollection. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahh Thank you! Our professor has not shown us what you have shown me here but this helps a lot and is much simpler!

Comment: @Martin Mulder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply

```
listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"data.txt");
```

without any `Stream`s (which should be ecnlosed into `using`)? Or

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"data.txt"));
```

`Stream` implementation could be something like that:

```
   using (StreamReader StreamIn = File.OpenText(@"data.txt")) { // <- using!
     for (String Record = StreamIn.ReadLine(); Record != null; Record = StreamIn.ReadLine()) {
       listBox1.Items.Add(Record);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Record)
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to use,

```
listBox1.Text += Record; // append
```

The `.Add()` function is a function in collections i.e. `List`, `IEnumerable` etc. You cannot use it in strings.

Or perhaps, you wanted to add a new item?

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Record);
```

This would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis to the end of ReadLine:

```
Record = StreamIn.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using a `using` statement. You can use `EndOfStream` instead of doing multiple readlines

```
using (StreamReader StreamIn = File.OpenText(@"data.txt"))
{
   while (!StreamIn.EndOfStream)
       listBox1.Text.Add(StreamIn.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"data.txt"))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx